# Is assignment an atomic operation in ruby MRI?

Tags: ruby, concurrency, atomic, mri

Let's say I have these two methods in my class.

```
def set_val(val)
  @val = val
end

def get_val
  @val
end
```

I'll spawn multiple threads to call `set_val` with different values. Is it guaranteed that reading from `@val` returns the correct value, i.e., not the last assigned value, but a value that was passed to `set_val`? Could I get something strange when reading? Is the assignment operation atomic? Is it indivisible irrespective of the number of threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a bit on the Ruby implementation you are using. As for MRI Ruby (the "default" Ruby), this is a safe (atomic) operation due to its Global Interpreter Lock which guards some operations such as assignments from bein interrupted by context switches.

JRuby also [guarantees](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Concurrency-in-jruby#language-features-and-the-jruby-runtime) that some operations are thread-safe, including assignment to instance variables.

In any case, please make sure to take into account that any such concurrent access can be serialized in a seemingly random way. That is, you can't guarantee which threads assigns first and which one last unless you use explicit locks such as a [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Mutex.html).

Comment: Could you provide the source of your answer for MRI?

Comment: Well, the whole idea of a GIL is to guarantee that individual operations on a Ruby level will never be interrupted by a concurrent thread. Even things like the += operator (which is definitely unsafe to use on JRuby and others) is [safe](https://github.com/jondot/pcwr/blob/dca092d03d060ece104e3aa7c1aef9efe2cd224e/README.md#state-of-the-union) on MRI.